# Handle file from WSGI request

Tags: python, post, file-upload, wsgi

## Question

What is a good way to handle a file that has been uploaded through a WSGI `POST` request?

## More info

So far, I'm able to read the raw `POST` data from `environ[wsgi.input]`. At this point the issue I am having is that the information associated with the file and the file itself are jammned together into one string:

```
'------WebKitFormBoundarymzmB1wyHKjyqZrDm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="new file.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav

THIS IS THE CONTENT
THIS IS THE CONTENT
THIS IS THE CONTENT
THIS IS THE CONTENT
THIS IS THE CONTENT

------WebKitFormBoundarymzmB1wyHKjyqZrDm--
'
```

Is there a library in python I should be using to handle information more cleanly? Ultimately, I'd like to take the file contents and then turn around and upload to Amazon S3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cgi.FieldStorage`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#higher-level-interface).

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'], environ=environ)
f = form['file'].file
# You can use `f` as a file object: f.read(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually you want much more abstraction than raw WSGI. Consider [frameworks that run on WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frameworks.html).